# OMSA on Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, dell, dell-openmanage

I have Dell OMSA installed on a PE1850 running Ubuntu Server 10.04 (using these instructions, pretty strait forward: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2336772&postcount=54). However when starting the OMSA web server (dsm_om_connsrv) I get the following error:

$./dsm_om_connsrv32d start

./dsm_om_connsrv32d: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

What does this mean? I think it means that my version of libstdc++5 is a 64 bit copy and this needs a 32 bit copy? Is that correct, and where can I get a 32 bit copy if that is indeed the case?

Comment: Solved: Installed libstdc++5 form here http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/libstdc++5/download using --force-architecture switch with dpkg

Comment: New problem :) running "/etc/init.d/dsm_om_connsvc start ; ps aux | grep dsm_om_connsrv" shows me it is running with the "-clrun" switch but "netstat -nl" shows one open port on 1311 (the default OMSA port), its "::::1311" which is IPv6 so this is presumably why I can't connect from another machine by browser to https://1.2.3.4:1311?

Comment: Solved: added IPv6 route to server :D Can't mark as answered though I don't have enough rep to do this so soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Installed libstdc++5 form here packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/libstdc++5/download using --force-architecture switch with dpkg